# factoryboy override attribute of lazy_attribute

Tags: python, factory-boy

I have some nested google.proto.message objects and am trying to override an attribute deep inside the parent model when making test data with factoryboy. Some of the children messages are created with a lazy_attribute which contains logic to populate them using other objects.
I've reproduced the issue I'm having in factoryboy with a much simpler example using `attrs` models.

```
class BookFactory(factory.Factory):
  class Meta:
    model = models.Book

  class Params:
    num_pages = 10

  @factory.lazy_attribute
  def pages(self):
    return PageFactory.build_batch(self.num_pages)


book = BookFactory.build(
  num_pages=3,
  pages__0__content='mypage0',
)

# This fails. How do I override pages[0].content with a BookFactory attribute?
assert book.pages[0].content == 'mypage0'
```

I have an running example of the failure at https://repl.it/@TomGoBravo/lazyattributesubfactory

Thank you for any suggestions you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be with a `SubFactory` wrapped in `factory.List`, but you'll lose the ability to adjust the length of said list:

```py
class BookFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Book

    pages = factory.List([
        factory.SubFactory(PageFactory),
        factory.SubFactory(PageFactory),
        factory.SubFactory(PageFactory),
    ])
```

Otherwise, you'd have to implement (and contribute !) some form of `SubFactoryList`, similar to the existing [`RelatedFactoryList`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#relatedfactorylist).

Comment: Is it fair to say that in general `factory.lazy_attribute` is fine for attributes that are a scalar or list of scalars, but this is (one of?) the downside(s) when used with an attribute that could be generated by a SubFactory?

Comment: Well, the main difference is that a `lazy_attribute` can only get parameters from the actual object; more complex declarations (`SubFactory`, `RelatedFactory`) also accept additional parameters with the `x__y` notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a post_generation method to control the number of items created as well as the attributes of the underlying model.

```
class BookFactory(factory.Factory):
  class Meta:
    model = models.Book

@factory.post_generation
def pages(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    if not create:
        return
    num_pages = kwargs.get('num_pages', 0)
    if num_pages > 0:
        book.pages = <---code goes here--->

book = BookFactory.build(
  pages__num_pages=3,
  pages__0__content='mypage0',
)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30557723)

Comment: @Flair - added example code to replace the link - thanks for the feedback